# why cant custom Exception be caught in generic catch clause

Tags: java, inheritance, exception, polymorphism

Please examine my custom exception below:

```
public class ReportException extends Exception {



    private int mCode = -1;
    private String mString = "";


    public ReportException(int code, String description)
    {
        super(description);
        mCode = code;
        mString = description;
    }


    public int getCode()
    {
        return mCode;
    }


    public String getString()
    {
        return mString;
    }
}
```

My question is why is this illegal in another class:

```
try{
       throw new NullPointerException();
   }
catch(ReportException e){

}
```

To me a NullPointerException is derived from Exception class and so is my custom ReportException so since there the same type i'd expect it can be caught in the catch clause. But my IDE says this is illegal.  I had this discussion with a  colleague of mine and he said there it cant be done but im just wondering why since they both derive from the same Exception class. This looks to defy polymorphism.

Comment: `"...NullPointerException is derived from Exception class and so is my custom ReportException so since there the same type..."` -- A dog is an animal and so is a cat, but that doesn't mean that a dog is a cat.

Comment: `NullPointerException` and `ReportException` are both `Exception`s, but `NullPointerException` is not a kind of `ReportException`.  In the same way, Germans and Italians are all Europeans, but Germans are not Italians.

Comment: @immibis False.  [Polymorphism.](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/java/IandI/polymorphism.html)  Which is, incidentally, what this question is actually about.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

A `NullPointerException` and your `ReportException` are both `Exception`s, but to catch a `ReportException`, you must throw a `ReportException` (or a subclass).  A `NullPointerException` is not a subclass of `ReportException`, so it's not caught.

Throw a `ReportException` instead.

Comment: Or catch Exception.  Or have a catch block for both to handle each independently.

Answer (score 0):

Some code inside the `try` block has to throw your checked exception before you can explicitly catch it.

This is valid:

```
try {
    throw new ReportException();
}
catch(ReportException e){
    // handle it
}
```

See [Java: checked vs unchecked exception explanation](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6115896/java-checked-vs-unchecked-exception-explanation)

Comment: This doesn't really have to do with checked vs. unchecked, though.  It's really a question about polymorphism.

Answer (score 0):

Every single class in java is a successor of java.lang.Object, but that doesn't mean that all of these classes are cast-able to each-other.

To a computer those two classes are completely different to each-other.